how to compile MinGW32 for C-SKY processors?
for C-SKY processors there is an IDE CDS for Windows, it uses MinGW, but it has a very old version of GCC 6.3, I would like to update to 13.2, how to do this correctly?
I tried to google and didn't find anything specific.
Tell me why, when compiling GCC for Windows in CYGWIN, it requires already compiled GCC for Linux???


Technically speaking you don't need MinGW. MinGW targets Windows systems, you want to target C-SKY systems.
Looking at https://github.com/c-sky/toolchain-build I see there are 2 common platforms for this architecture, identified by triplets csky-unknown-linux-gnu and csky-unknown-elf.
So you need to decide which platform you will be targetting exactly.
Then you will need a GCC compiler to target that platform.
If you want to have that compiler on Windows you will need a Windows version of that compiler.
If there's no download for it you may need to build your own (possibly using the above link in an MSYS2 shell).
There may also be an alternative. Besides GCC you can may also use LLVM to target these platforms.

Well, I compiled the toolchain and replaced it in the IDE, but now when building the firmware I get the following error: d:/c-sky/cds/mingw/csky-elfabiv2-tools/bin/../lib/gcc/csky-elfabiv2/12.4.0/../../../../csky-elfabiv2/bin/ld.exe: error: no memory region specified for loadable section `.eh_frame'

this applies to a C++ project, if the project is C, then this error does not exist and everything compiles

For C++ it's better to link with g++ instead of ld.

The first step involves downloading the new GCC version. Visit the MinGW-w64 website and navigate to the download section. Here, you will select the GCC 13.2 version compatible with your system architecture, either 32-bit or 64-bit. Depending on your preference, you can either download the installer, which simplifies the process by automating the installation, or you can opt for the binary archive, which requires manual setup.
If you choose the installer, run it and follow the on-screen instructions to install the MinGW-w64 toolchain with GCC 13.2. Make sure to select a different installation directory from your existing MinGW setup to avoid any conflicts. On the other hand, if you download the binary archive, extract the contents to a directory of your choice, such as C:\mingw64\.
Next, you need to configure the CDS IDE to use the new GCC version. Open the CDS IDE and navigate to the settings or preferences section, usually found under compiler or build settings. Locate the paths for the compiler toolchain and update them to point to the new MinGW-w64 GCC 13.2 installation directory, for example, C:\mingw64\bin.
To verify the update, open a terminal or command prompt and navigate to the bin directory of your new GCC installation (cd C:\mingw64\bin). Run the command gcc --version to ensure that GCC 13.2 is correctly installed. The output should confirm the installation of GCC 13.2.
Finally, it is essential to test the new setup. Create a simple project in the CDS IDE and attempt to build and run it to ensure that the new GCC compiler is functioning correctly. This step will help identify any potential issues related to the updated GCC version.
Before making these changes, it is advisable to back up your current MinGW installation and CDS IDE configuration to prevent any loss of data. Additionally, ensure that your system’s PATH environment variable includes the path to the new GCC binaries if you are building projects from the command line. Referring to the CDS IDE documentation or community forums can provide further assistance if you encounter any issues during this process.

the problem is, as I understand it, ready-made MinGW GCC assemblies are already compiled for x86_64

I don’t understand mingw initially means that files will be created for Windows (exe), here is a script that downloads and compiles everything, but the files are not exe, but run on Linux https://github.com/Zeranoe/mingw-w64-build

turns out it uses standard gcc and not i686-w64-mingw32-gcc, how to fix this?

i686-w64-mingw32-gcc is an indication that that gcc is set up to build for the i686 platform on windows. You want to cross-compile for c-sky, so I'd expect a different name.

that's right, I need gcc running in Windows, but with -arch=csky
